# Creating DataFrame based on two or more non equal lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two lists let's say

```
list1 = ["apple","banana"]
list2 = ["M","T","W","TR","F","S"]
```

I want to create a data frame of two columns fruit and day so that the result will look something like this

| fruit | day |
| --- | --- |
| apple | M |
| apple | T |
| apple | W |
| apple | TR |
| apple | F |
| apple | S |
| banana | M |

and so on...

currently, my actual data is columnar meaning items in list2 are in columns, but I want them in rows, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify how the mapping between the two unequal lists should work a little more?

Comment: e.g. list1 element1 should have all of the elements in list2. so in the case above. apple will be duplicated until all of the values in list2 are assigned a row in day column. then banana or element2 will start and it will be duplicated until all of list2 values are assigned a row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
from itertools import product
import pandas as pd


list1 = ["apple","banana"]
list2 = ["M","T","W","TR","F","S"]
df = pd.DataFrame(
    product(list1, list2),
    columns=['fruit', 'day']
)
print(df)
>>>
    fruit   day
0   apple   M
1   apple   T
2   apple   W
3   apple   TR
4   apple   F
5   apple   S
6   banana  M
7   banana  T
8   banana  W
9   banana  TR
10  banana  F
11  banana  S
```

Comment: looks like product from itertools does the trick and Thank you that is what i needed

Answer (score 1):

same result with `merge`:

```
df = pd.merge(pd.Series(list1,name='fruit'),
              pd.Series(list2,name='day'),how='cross')

print(df)
'''
     fruit day
0    apple   M
1    apple   T
2    apple   W
3    apple  TR
4    apple   F
5    apple   S
6   banana   M
7   banana   T
8   banana   W
9   banana  TR
10  banana   F
11  banana   S
```